# How to Expire Asp.net session in time bound

Tags: asp.net

Hi my problem is in my application i want to expire a session when user is in idel for 5 minutes and then the page want to redirect to login page and when user login I Want TO Redirected to Session expired page directly please send me the solution

Am using following code to Expire a session my page also redircted to login after user login i want to redirected to the session expired page

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="2"></sessionState>
```

Comment: Please re-word your question. It is hard to understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: after session expire my page is redirected to login page in login page after giving user name and password my page want to redirect to previous session expired page........

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.web>
<sessionState timeout="60" />
```

.........

and this is in seconds 
60 means 1 minute ...

u can use also Session.Abandon();

if u want in 5 min u should put 300

and if u want to direct to any page after session is expire 
u can do it by `if(session["session_name"]==null)
{response.redirect("page_name");}`

Comment: how to get previous session expired page url

Comment: u should put session["sessionname"]="";

Comment: how to put["session Name"] for total pages of my application

Comment: see ... when u create a any session u should give it a name and also enable this session ...
just tell me what u want to do i will help u 
and send u the code solution and just y will paste it .. :)